# How can I dress up clothing objects with a python script?

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, parent

[image: blender]

As seen in the picture, I have a collection of clothes consisting of different objects. I need to dress these clothing objects on the model. But I have to do this with code because I should be able to do the same as the clothes change.

I thought about linking objects together. But I couldn't find how to do this.
I thought of doing parent and child operation. How can I do this with coding?
Or what other method can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position all the cloth items in the same position and parent them all to the character with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and control their viewport and render visibilities using python. In this example below I have 3 cloth items and you can set the name of the cloth item to be visible.

[image]

[image]

Here's the script which you can use in the [`Text Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html):

```
import bpy

cloth_collection = "Cloth-Collection"
cloth_objects = bpy.data.collections[cloth_collection].objects


def show_cloth_item(cloth_obj, show=True):
    hide = not show
    cloth_obj.hide_render = hide
    cloth_obj.hide_viewport = hide
    cloth_obj.hide_set(hide)

def hide_all_clothes(hide=True):
    for cloth_obj in cloth_objects:
        print(cloth_obj)
        show_cloth_item(cloth_obj, False)

def get_cloth_object(cloth_name):
    return cloth_objects[cloth_name]

hide_all_clothes()

cloth_obj = get_cloth_object('Cloth.001')
show_cloth_item(cloth_obj)
```